# How to install vagrantbox from a downloaded file

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant

I have decided to install a `vagrant box` (laravel/homestead) using a downloaded file from `atlas` on `ubuntu 16.04`. I ran the following command to install the box (from the downloaded file) by running the command below:
`vagrant box add laravel/homestead ./vagrantbox.box`
Now, as running `vagrant up` yields me some error messages, I decided to check the status of the machine by running `vagrant status` and the return is:

> Current machine states:
>
> homestead-7               not created (virtualbox)
>
> The environment has not yet been created. Run `vagrant up` to create
>   the environment. If a machine is not created, only the default
>   provider will be shown. So if a provider is not listed, then the
>   machine is not created for that environment.

But when I run `vagrant box list` it returns:

> laravel/homestead (virtualbox, 0)

I am totally confused about what I should do, so I would like to ask you to help me make it up and running. Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

So, here is the answer I have found until now:
`1 -` As I noticed, the folder created by this method was named as `0` yet I had installed version `6.0.0` of the box. I therefore changed the folder name from `0` to `6` in the following path:

> /home/my-username/.vagrant.d/boxes/laravel-VAGRANTSLASH-homestead

`2 -` The next thing was to add a file  called `metadata_url` to the very same address as said above, containing the url_address leading to the box download address. In my case:

> https://vagrantcloud.com/laravel/boxes/homestead

The box is now working properly fine (after it created a machine called `homestead-7` in virtualbox console), with only a few warnings about not being able to update the box if the user requires it. As it says there shall be an error in allowed characters used in `metada_url` content. But it works and it is very nice to be able to re-install the box over and over.